Taylor and Francis Journal Reference creation
I'm preparing a paper for a Taylor and Francis journal. It is instructing me the following for creating the Reference section - "Instead of typing the bibliography by hand, you may prefer to create the list of
references using a BibTEX database. In order to do this, the tfs.bst file needs to be in your working folder or an appropriate directory, and the lines
\bibliographystyle{tfs}
\bibliography{interacttfssample}
included where the list of references is to appear, where tfs.bst is the name of the BibTEX bibliography style file for Taylor & Francis’ Reference Style S and interacttfssample.bib is the bibliographic database included with the Interact-TFS LATEX bundle (to be replaced with the name of your own .bib file)."
However I'm not sure how to get tfs.bst file. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I need the tfs.bst file. Im not sure where to get it from.

Can you tell us which journal you are going to submit to and where you found the instructions you are quoting in the question? I'd expect there to be a download to a "LaTeX template" or some such that hopefully includes all relevant files somewhere in the author instructions.

The journal is "Journal of Applied Statistics". There is a latex template in "https://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?show=instructions&journalCode=cjas20#formatting-and-templates". This template suggests to use tfs.bst file for referencing but Im not able to find this file.

The .zip file that I can download from https://files.taylorandfrancis.com/InteractTFSLaTeX.zip  (it is linked at https://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?show=instructions&journalCode=cjas20#formatting-and-templates) contains tfs.bst. It's probably a good idea to use the interacttfssample.tex file contained there as a basis for your submission.

Thank you for this. I can download the tfs.bst file. Im using overleaf to produce my article. I have uploaded the tfs.bst file into my overleaf project and included my list of references into interacttfssample.tex file. But I'm getting an error stating "I couldn't open database file interacttfssample.bib : \bibdata{interacttfssample : }". Any suggestions here?

You need to pass the name of your .bib file to the \bibliography command. It looks as though you copied the call from the template, which has \bibliography{interacttfssample}. This will only work if your .bib file is called interacttfssample.bib.
